# UI not updating despite watching provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I am using Riverpod and have set up a Provider and Notifier for my data, however when I modify the data in the provider, my UI is not reflecting that change. If I save and hot-reload my app, the new values are shown.

For context, my Board contains a property that is a Map of Players and their Scores. On my Board screen, I am iterating through a list conversion of the 'boardData' map for a GridView.builder, like so:

```
    ref.read(boardProvider.notifier).loadBoard(widget.board);
    final providedBoard = ref.watch(boardProvider);

    List<MapEntry<PlayerModel, int>> boardDataList =
        providedBoard.boardData.entries.toList();


      body: GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2, //1.5
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        ),
        itemCount: providedBoard.boardData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => BoardPlayerGridItem(
          player: boardDataList[index].key,
          score: boardDataList[index].value,
        ),
      ),
```

Here is my BoardModel class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import 'package:counter/models/player_model.dart';

const uuid = Uuid();

class BoardModel {
  BoardModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.icon,
    required this.initialValue,
    required this.increment,
    required this.boardData,
    required this.owner,
    required this.isManaged,
    required this.isOnline,
    required this.autosaveEnabled,
    required this.lastUpdated,
    String? id,
  }) : id = id ?? uuid.v4();

  final String id;
  final String name;
  final Icon icon;
  final int initialValue; // default to 0
  final int increment; // default to 1
  final Map<PlayerModel, int> boardData; // Players and scores for the board
  final PlayerModel owner;
  final bool isManaged; // Only owner can make changes
  final bool isOnline; // Saved to cloud
  final bool autosaveEnabled;
  final DateTime lastUpdated;
}
```

Here is my provider:

```
class BoardNotifier extends StateNotifier<BoardModel> {
  BoardNotifier() : super(sampleBoard);

  // Load the currently viewed board into notifier
  loadBoard(BoardModel board) {
    state = board;
  }

  // Update the player's score in the board by the configured increment
  incrementPlayerScore(BoardModel board, PlayerModel player) {
    board.boardData.update(player, (value) => value + board.increment);

    // Update our board in state
    state = board;
  }
}

final boardProvider = StateNotifierProvider<BoardNotifier, BoardModel>((ref) {
  return BoardNotifier();
});
```

Here is my BoardPlayerGridItem (the widget in the GridView) that is not updating.

```
class BoardPlayerGridItem extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const BoardPlayerGridItem({
    super.key,
    required this.player,
    required this.score,
  });

  final PlayerModel player;
  final int? score;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _BoardPlayerGridItemState();
}

class _BoardPlayerGridItemState extends ConsumerState<BoardPlayerGridItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final providedBoard = ref.watch(boardProvider);

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        ref.watch(boardProvider.notifier).incrementPlayerScore(
              providedBoard,
              widget.player,
            );
      },
      onLongPress: () {}, // Open edit form
      child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.player.name,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .titleMedium!
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              widget.score.toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .displayLarge!
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The UI is a grid of tiles and tapping on each increments the counter. I thought by adding watching my boardProvider and then changing it as per the onTap function, that would prompt the rebuild, but seems not. Any pointers appciated.

Comment: Can you show the `BoardModel` class?

Comment: Edited question with BoardModel class. I do not have a copyWith method but will look at creating one now.

Comment: Using the copyWith method did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside `incrementPlayerScore`, you're already updating the board before reassigning the `state`. This is why it's important to use [immutable state](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/why_immutability).

As a workaround, you can make a local variable inside `incrementPlayerScore` that copy the `board` state first and make modifications on that copied variable. You haven't shown the `BoardModel` class, but I assume it should have some kind of `copyWith` method. If so, you can do this:

```
incrementPlayerScore(BoardModel board, PlayerModel player) {
  final newBoard = board.copyWith();
  newBoard.boardData.update(player, (value) => value + board.increment);

  // Update our board in state
  state = newBoard;
}
```

(Note: there could be a better way to use the `copyWith` that is by assigning the new `boardData` with the `boardData` parameter of `copyWith`)

---

Additionally, you should use `ref.read` instead of `ref.watch` inside the `onTap` of `GestureDetector`.